# Does it ever make sense to use Queueable to enqueue a Batch Apex class?

Tags: batch, queueable-apex

A simple question.

Does it ever make sense to use Queueable to enqueue a Batch Apex job?

If I enqueue a Queueable job that executes a Batch Apex job, is it the same as if I executed a batch job from Batch Apex directly?

They are both asynchronous interfaces.

Cheers.

Comment: For the specific description you have provided, absolutely does not make any sense and will simply waste one of your daily async invocation limits.

Comment: @Phil W: Thanks a lot!